# Classe Django View mantém os valores

Tags: python, django, classes

Uma curiosidade que tem me acompanhado há um bom tempo no Django e nunca consegui sanar:

Seguinte. Digamos que eu tenho algo do tipo:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

from pagina.models import Config

class BasicView(View):
  try:
    dados = {
      'email': Config.objects.get(variavel = 'email').valor,
    }
  except:
    dados = {}

class TelaView(BasicView):
  def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.template_name = 'base.html'
    return render(request, self.template_name, self.dados)
```

Então, no template base.html, eu chamaria por {{email}} e o django mostraria o cadastro no banco de dados.

Agora, se eu mantivesse o servidor rodando e modificasse o registro do e-mail no banco de dados, para que o novo e-mail apareça no template, seria necessário parar o servidor e rodá-lo novamente.

Minha pergunta: Por que isso acontece e como contornar isso?

Comment: Ninguém passou por essa situação antes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque quando o python vai executar um script ele cria uma espécie de cache do arquivos envolvidos (aqueles arquivos `tralala.pyc` ou então os arquivos que ficam dentro do diretório `__pycache__`). Logo, ele realiza a importação de informações entre *files* apenas uma vez (quando é executado), não toda vez que a view é chamada.

Isso é um comportamento padrão da própria linguagem, se precisa fornecer essa informação dinamicamente (ela irá ser alterada de tempos em tempos), procure uma forma de armazena-la no banco de dados através de um objeto e use algum queryset para buscar a mesma.

Caso ajude, [aqui](http://consutar) tem a documentação sobre querysets e [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/) a documentação sobre bancos de dados. 
Caso não tenha sido completamente claro, espero ao menos ter ajudado.

Comment: Rapaz... Sua resposta foi muito pertinente. Eu imaginava algo assim mesmo. Mas digamos que eu tenha, além do TelaView, umas outras 4 views e, em todas, tenho que carregar a variável 'email' do exemplo. Você conhece alguma forma de eu fazer isso sem ter que repetir a linha self.dados['email'] = Config.objects.get(variavel = 'email').valor para cada view? Como você faz isso em seus projetos?

Comment: Procure sobre python and environment variables (Python e variáveis de ambiente).